# How to pass form variable in submit? ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have the following rendered:

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleCompanySubmit}>
  <label>
    <input placeholder="put company name here" />
  </label>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Here is the event handler:

```
handleCompanySubmit(event) {
  console.log("company submit")
  event.preventDefault(); 
  this.setState({company: event.target.value })
}
```

The following is in the constructor:

```
this.handleCompanySubmit = this.handleCompanySubmit.bind(this);
```

I don't know why it won't work. The value event isn't being passed through, I am unsure why.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `value` of the `target` of the submit event will not be the value of the input inside the form.

You could e.g. keep the input `value` in the `company` state variable and use that when the form is submitted instead.

**Example**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    company: ""
  };

  onChange = e => {
    this.setState({ company: e.target.value });
  };

  handleCompanySubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state.company);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleCompanySubmit}>
        <label>
          <input
            placeholder="put company name here"
            value={this.state.company}
            onChange={this.onChange}
          />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need an id for each input inside the form.
Then you access them on the handler with event.target.elements.id.value.

```js
class App extends React.Component {

  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(event.target.elements.company.value);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          <input
            placeholder="put company name here"
            id="company"
          />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```